# How to open this kind of ceiling light

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling, light, light-bulb

I need to change the bulb for one of the washroom lights. How this can be opened?

I tried rotating and pulling down.[image]

Comment: Normally they sort of clipped on so pulling on one side near where its attached... a little more enthusiastically tends to work

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell but there appears to be a set screw, typically there are three that need to be loosened to remove the cover.

Hold the cover with one hand and loosen the screws until it lowers and can be removed.

[image: light cover]

Comment: Yes, there are typically these "thumb screws" around the rim (usually 3) that retain a lip on the glass cover.  Once you loosen them, they release the lip.